# How to make third section of images align top?

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this for a while now and have looked up resource after resource and I can't find a solution to my problem.

The third section of images (class="mtt3") Won't align to the top of the other section images. When I add a new image, it adds it at the "bottom' so to speak. How can I get these images to align to the top next to the others?

Or is there a more efficient way to create three rows of images?
Originally I wanted three rows and for them all to be aligned horizontally. But even doing inline-block and float: left, I could not achieve this.

That last part doesn't need to be answered, the focal point of this question is getting the dang mtt3 section images to align to the top of the other two sections.

Go to full page to see what I'm talking about when you run it.

```css
 .meettheteam { text-align: center; background-color: #f2707e; color: #ffffff; }
  
  .banner { max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; padding-top: 2%; }
  
  .mtt, .mtt2, .mtt3 { display: inline-block; top 0px; left: 20px; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }
```

```html
<div class="meettheteam">
  <section class="banner">
    <img  src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576445849f74567f15556571/1466189188385/STL-Meettheteam-Mobile.png" alt="meet the team banner">
  </section>

  <section class="mtt">
    
    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577bab87cd0f68c0f2524dc1/1467722631930/STL-Team-Hannah.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
    <figcaption>Hannah</figcaption> 
    
    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577babd3cd0f68c0f2524fb8/1467722707482/STL-Team-Gracie.png">
      <figcaption>Gracie</figcaption>
    
    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577badc837c58134dd1f6d4f/1467723208878/STL-Team-Carrigan.png">
      <figcaption>Carrigan</figcaption>
    
</section>

  <section class="mtt2">
    
    <img style="width: 85%;"
 src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577babffcd0f68c0f25250ca/1467722751989/STL-Team-Hart.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Hart</figcaption>
    
    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577bac26cd0f68c0f25251a3/1467722791264/STL-Team-Alyx.png">
      <figcaption>Alyx</figcaption>
    
    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577bac97579fb30e7f442827/1467722904067/STL-Team-Erin-H.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
    <figcaption>Erin</figcaption>
    
  </section>
  
  <section class="mtt3">
    
    <img style="width: 85%;"
 src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577bae0037c58134dd1f6f5b/1467723265219/STL-Team-Jennie.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
      <figcaption>Hart</figcaption>
    
 <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577bac46cd0f68c0f252523b/1467722822562/STL-Team-Kaityln.png">
    <figcaption>Kaitlyn</figcaption>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: As the first question is already answered, i'd suggest you to use flexbox to do that in the future. Here is a very good tutorial on how to use it : [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Solid, thanks! I've heard about flexbox but haven't messed with it much yet. i will do that.

Comment: It is an awesome tool, let me suggest you [flexy boxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) it will help you understand how it works :)

Comment: Wow this is really cool. I've never seen a demo web app like this. Awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your `.mtt, .mtt2, .mtt3` rules add `vertical-align:top`

```css
.meettheteam {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f2707e;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.banner {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 2%;
}
.mtt,
.mtt2,
.mtt3 {
  display: inline-block;
  top 0px;
  left: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="meettheteam">
  <section class="banner">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/576445849f74567f15556571/1466189188385/STL-Meettheteam-Mobile.png" alt="meet the team banner">
  </section>

  <section class="mtt">

    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577bab87cd0f68c0f2524dc1/1467722631930/STL-Team-Hannah.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
    <figcaption>Hannah</figcaption>

    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577babd3cd0f68c0f2524fb8/1467722707482/STL-Team-Gracie.png">
    <figcaption>Gracie</figcaption>

    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577badc837c58134dd1f6d4f/1467723208878/STL-Team-Carrigan.png">
    <figcaption>Carrigan</figcaption>

  </section>

  <section class="mtt2">

    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577babffcd0f68c0f25250ca/1467722751989/STL-Team-Hart.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
    <figcaption>Hart</figcaption>

    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577bac26cd0f68c0f25251a3/1467722791264/STL-Team-Alyx.png">
    <figcaption>Alyx</figcaption>

    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577bac97579fb30e7f442827/1467722904067/STL-Team-Erin-H.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
    <figcaption>Erin</figcaption>

  </section>

  <section class="mtt3">

    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577bae0037c58134dd1f6f5b/1467723265219/STL-Team-Jennie.png" alt="Meet the Team Images">
    <figcaption>Hart</figcaption>

    <img style="width: 85%;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/577bac46cd0f68c0f252523b/1467722822562/STL-Team-Kaityln.png">
    <figcaption>Kaitlyn</figcaption>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! Why could I not find that anywhere as a solution? So simple. Thank's for the quick help, that did it. Cheers! I'll vote up once it lets me.